# Netbeans 8 Cannot Load Even Default Layout, Using Internally predefined configuration

Tags: netbeans

I just moved Netbeans 8.2 installation directory to new computer, set up jdkhome on netbeans.conf to java 1.8.

When I tried to run Netbeans and some strange error appears,

```
Cannot load even default layout, using internally predefined configuration
```

Than, I choose OK.

And than my Netbeans hang, I cannot do something on there. Try to figure out by looking on Google but no article discuss similar topic.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

**Edit 1**
After do simple research, here are log of my Netbeans

```
notation: From: nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/org-netbeans-api-project-libraries/Libraries/restapi.xml
Annotation: From: nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/org-netbeans-api-project-libraries/Libraries/restapi.xml
Annotation: From: nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/org-netbeans-api-project-libraries/Libraries/restapi.xml
From: nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/org-netbeans-api-project-libraries/Libraries/restapi.xml
From: nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/org-netbeans-api-project-libraries/Libraries/restapi.xml
Caused: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\root\idk\netbeans\NetBeans 8.2\ergonomics\modules\org-netbeans-modules-ide-ergonomics.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:109)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:152)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.layers.BinaryFS$BFSFile.getInputStream(BinaryFS.java:906)
Caused: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Cannot find 'jar:file:/D:/root/idk/netbeans/NetBeans%208.2/ergonomics/modules/org-netbeans-modules-ide-ergonomics.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/ide/ergonomics/enterprise/org-netbeans-modules-websvc-swdp-restapi.xml'
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.layers.BinaryFS$BFSFile.getInputStream(BinaryFS.java:909)
    at org.openide.filesystems.MultiFileObject.getInputStream(MultiFileObject.java:666)
    at org.openide.filesystems.MultiFileObject.getInputStream(MultiFileObject.java:666)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.libraries.LibrariesStorage$1.call(LibrariesStorage.java:286)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.libraries.LibrariesStorage$1.call(LibrariesStorage.java:281)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.libraries.FileLockManager.readAction(FileLockManager.java:76)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.libraries.LibrariesStorage.readLibrary(LibrariesStorage.java:279)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.project.libraries.LibrariesStorage.loadFromStorage(LibrariesStorage.java:167)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.libraries.LibrariesStorage.initStorage(LibrariesStorage.java:244)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.libraries.LibrariesStorage.getLibraries(LibrariesStorage.java:347)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.libraries.LibrariesModule.run(LibrariesModule.java:72)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of potential issues:

[1] The stack trace shows you are getting a **FileNotFoundException** for this file:

> D:\root\idk\netbeans\NetBeans
>   8.2\ergonomics\modules\org-netbeans-modules-ide-ergonomics.jar

Does it actually exist on the new machine? Have you possibly installed to a different drive, or mistyped the folder location when you were setting up NetBeans? In particular, one of the folders for that missing jar file is **idk** - should that be **jdk**, or possibly removed altogether? Make sure that you really do have the file **org-netbeans-modules-ide-ergonomics.jar** in that folder on the new computer.

[2] As a separate matter, NetBeans uses a **Cache directory** and a **User directory**. On a working system you can see the absolute names of those directories using **Help > About**. If you still have access to your other instance of NetBeans use that to get the names of those directories, and create them on your new system if they don't exist. Having an empty cache directory on your new system should not be an issue, but the User Directory contains configuration information (e.g. your preferences, plugin data) which will be missing on your new system. That missing information may give you some tedious problems, but it shouldn't prevent you using NetBeans altogether.

On your new computer you can override the locations of the cache directory and user directory in **netbeans.conf** (look for **netbeans_default_userdir** and 
**netbeans_default_cachedir**), but it is probably best to use the default values.

All that said, NetBeans is so simple to install that you may be causing more problems than you solve by copying the installation directory from one machine to another. Why not just install NetBeans from scratch on your new machine? Once you have done that you can:

- Reinstall plugins as needed.
- Export your NetBeans preferences from your old machine to a zip file (**Tools > Options > Export...**).
- Inmport those preferences on your new machine from that zip file (**Tools > Options > Import...**).